# How to Implement real time face unlock feature in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I need to implement real-time face unlock feature in my flutter app, please suggest the best way to do it, I'm also learned about ML_kit(firebase) and openCV but both support face detection and I'm looking for face recognition.

Please suggest any library or SDK for Flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you only want this feature for iOS and you're using an iPhone X, you can use [local_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) package.

You can use it this way:

```
initializeFaceRecognition() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      bool canCheckBiometrics = await _localAuth.canCheckBiometrics;
      if (!canCheckBiometrics) {
        setState(() => _authenticationResult = 'This device does not support biometrics');
        return;
      }
      List<BiometricType> availableBiometrics = await _localAuth.getAvailableBiometrics();
      if (!availableBiometrics.contains(BiometricType.face)) {
        setState(() => _authenticationResult = 'This device does not support face recognition');
        return;
      }
      bool didAuthenticate = await _localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(localizedReason: 'Authenticate with face recognition', useErrorDialogs: true);
      if (didAuthenticate) {
        setState(() => _authenticationResult = 'Authenticated');
      } else {
        setState(() => _authenticationResult = 'Not authenticated');
      }
    } else {
      setState(() => _authenticationResult = 'Not compatible platform');
    }
  }
```

Now if you want it for Android, that's not possible at the time, as Face Recognition is not being exposed on an API, like fingerprint does.

In that case, you should create your own ML models and API for face recognition or use an API like [Face API from Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/) (and that won't be real time, you have to upload pictures). But at this point, it should be another question, as it's out of the scope of a Flutter app.

I've found [Trueface](https://docs.trueface.ai/docs/tools-by-os-platform) API, that apparently allows you to detect faces from a live stream. Maybe this service is closer to what you need (it's not free).

Comment: is face authentication NOT supported on Android even today? what about pixel phones?

Comment: @AnV Have you get any success for Face Recognition in Flutter? I did created a sample project where it's working and now in actual project it's not working. I've ready docs properly and something got for Android 10 (Q - API 29) version to call directly. But for an update from Android 9 (API level 28), permission `USE_FINGERPRINT` is deprecated and they suggested to use `USE_BIOMETRIC` .